# Entity Framework Core code-first approach: database not being created automatically

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, migration, code-first, database-create

I'm having an issue with Entity Framework Core while trying to use the code-first approach.

I want the database to be automatically created when I run the code, but it's not happening.

If I don't create the database beforehand, I get an error stating that the relevant table cannot be found.

Here's my context file:

```
public class IBKSContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=DataAccess.Contexts.IBKSContext;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true");
    }

    public DbSet<Api> Apis { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Calibration> Calibrations { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Channel> Channels { get; set; }
    public DbSet<DB12> DB12s { get; set; }
}
```

NuGet packages installed in my project:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 7.0.8
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design 7.0.8
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 7.0.8
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 7.0.8
```

I'd appreciate your help. I'm not sure how to proceed, but I really need to get this working.

Thank you in advance for your responses.

Answer (score 0):

You could call the method `context.Database.EnsureCreated()` to create the database if it does not exist (see [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/ensure-created)).

Comment: Negative. The documentation you are linking to contains a big **Warning**: *"`EnsureCreated` and Migrations don't work well together. If you're using Migrations, don't use `EnsureCreated` to initialize the schema."*